# Replacing null values automatically for a specific set of tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to write a query that can update all values on any given table to this `--` given that I have many columns across multiple tables the function needs to be universal meaning i can run it without specifying column names, for it simply to identify null values and update them with my value of `--` I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this and wrap it into a function I can call when someone INSERTS into any of the tables affected.

I've looked at `COALESE` as a possible option but any examples would be appreciated.

My table looks like: (I have over 30 tables with 100+ fields so writing out Updates for each field individually sounds like a nightmare, there must be a better way)

```
ID  Name    Email           Phone
1   John    john@aol.com    234-234-2344
2   Mary    mary@test.com   332-134-5424
3   Simon   null            null
4   Kevin   null            345-453-2135
5   Kelly   kelly@msn.com   null
```

I'd like to replace all `nulls` with `--` permanantly in my table probably using an `UPDATE` statement.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Aside: That implies that everything nullable is stored as a string. Makes me wonder whether data types have been used appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following SQL will help you to list down all the tables and column names. And you can build a dynamic SQL thingy around this result set to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       --SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
       t.name AS TableName,
       c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.tables AS t
     INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

**EDIT**:

Otherwise, the following link got a solution to your problem.

[SQL Server Find and Replace Values in All Tables and All Text Columns](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1555/sql-server-find-and-replace-values-in-all-tables-and-all-text-columns/)

Comment: Hello Viking, Thank you for this reply. I will attempt this on my end and see if I can accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, you are really overcomplicating this.  I would suggest instead:

```
alter table t
    alter column phone not null default '--';
```

Before doing this, update the column so there are no `NULL` values:

```
update t
    set phone = '--'
    where phone is null;
```

And, I should throw in that I think this is a bad idea.  You are confusing "data" with "representation".  In an application, you want to show `--` for a `NULL` value.  But I think `NULL` is the best way to represent the missing value in a database.

(And, of course, you need to do the above for each column you care about.)

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific to my issue.